# python gspread updating multiple cells from reponse body

Tags: python, api, gspread

I am using this python script to take a response from Progresso API:
http://docs.progresso.apiary.io/#reference/behaviour/behaviour-events-collection/get-behaviour-events

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
import smtplib import gspread 
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentialseaders = {
'Authorization': 'Bearer [CURRENT_TOKEN]'
}
request = Request('https://private-anon-ae5edf57e7-progresso.apiary-
mock.com/BMEvents/?Behaviour=new', headers=headers)
response_body = urlopen(request).read()
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('ProgressoAPI-
2f6ecaa6635c.json', scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
wks  = gc.open("Progresso Test").sheet1
wks.clear()
cell_list = wks.range('A1:H20')
for cell in cell_list:
cell.value = response_body
wks.update_cells(cell_list)
```

I know the cell.value = response body is wrong and I don't know how I can get it right - I am stuck.

it appears in every cell like this:
"{
    ""BehaviourEntryId"": 13798177,
    ""LearnerId"": 245277,
    ""LearnerCode"": ""2009-0080"",
    ""RegGroup"": ""U6-RWE"",
    ""Behaviour"": ""Negative"",
    ""IncidentDate"": ""2017-02-07"",
    ""Subject"": ""BE"",
    ""Location"": ""CLS"",
    ""Published"": ""Yes"",
    ""Creator"": ""DhDr"",
    ""Editor"": null,
    ""Assignee"": ""DiRo"",
    ""Status"": ""Completed"",
    ""Details"": [
                  {
                    ""Category"": ""CL"",
                    ""Type"": ""CLatt"",
                    ""Severity"": ""S2"",
                    ""point"": 0
                  },
                  {
                    ""Category"": ""CL"",
                    ""Type"": ""CLBEH"",
                    ""Severity"": ""S2"",
                    ""point"": 2
                  }
                ],
    ""Comments"": [
                  {
                    ""BehaviourEntryCommentId"": 5648278,
                    ""Confidential"": true,
                    ""Comment"": ""Asked to go to the toilet and went to the one furthest away just to waste time.""
                  },
                  {
                    ""BehaviourEntryCommentId"": 5648279,
                    ""Confidential"": false,
                    ""Comment"": ""Spat gum out on floor""
                  },
                  {
                    ""BehaviourEntryCommentId"": 5648280,
                    ""Confidential"": false,
                    ""Comment"": ""Was rude to memeber of Staff""
                  }
                ],
    ""Actions"":  [
                  ""HTO"",
                  ""ISO""
                ]
}"

How do I separate the text to how I want in the cell range and bulk update it?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean something like two columns with one row being "BehaviourEntryId" and the other row being 13798177, you can try something like this:

```
import json
response = json.loads(response_body) #decode the json response string, returns a dict
response_pairs = list(response.items)

for i in range(1, len(response_body)+1):
    current_pair = response_pairs[i-1]
    current_key =  current_pair[0]
    current_value = current_pair[1]
    wks.update_acell('A{}'.format(i), current_key)
    wks.update_acell('B{}'.format(i), current_value)
```

Comment: Wheres the best place to add this to the code? I add this and it keeps giving invalid syntax errors.

Comment: I'm not so sure without knowing the entire code. Where are the syntax errors at? Import should always be placed at the top of your code though.